# Disabling Sunday from Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to disable "Sunday" from being selected in the "datepicker" in our online booking script. I have searched on Google with hundreds of solutions, but none seem to take effect within the script when implemented.

Here is the script: http://pastebin.com/TxzMs4y4

I know I am overlooking this by just line of code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `beforeShowDay`:-

```
$this.datepicker($.extend(dOpts, {
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [(date.getDay() != 0), '']; // 0 => Sunday
    }
}));
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/znmgeaj8/)** is a stripped down version of your `datepicker` for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It has been resolved :)

Comment: Was is the `beforeShowDay`? if so an upvote/mark as correct would be appreciated :)

Comment: Yup. It sure was :) Marked as correct! Wish I could upvote, too new :(

Comment: BG101, I know you were so great at helping me before. On top of blocking Sundays within the script I provided (solved) - can you help me in blocking specific dates? Like blocking specific dates from the calendar that I specify in the script.

Comment: The easiest was to achieve that is, have an array of date strings and before the `return`, iterate through the array and check if `date` is there. if it is then `return [false,''];`. I just googled *Datepicker disable specific dates* and there's loads of examples which use the `beforeShowDay`. good luck :)

Comment: I still can't thank you enough. I've tried all of the solutions through search but for some reason, either the dates all become unselectable or the date picker doesn't appear. I know your time is valuable, but if you're interested in taking a peek, visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664852/disable-specific-dates-in-datepicker